# What is the name of this type of transition?

Tags: transitions

What is the name of this type of transition [in this video](https://player.vimeo.com/video/254489721)? How can I recreate it in Sony Vegas or other video software?

Comment: https://vimeo.com/254489721

Comment: It doesn't really have a specific name. Since it is an animation, the closest you could probably get with just editing software is a double linear wipe from the center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this double linear wipe as *"Barn doors"* transition in Sony Vegas video editor.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't bar*n* doors?

Answer (score 0):

You can make it with animation composer plugin

[animation composer plugin](https://misterhorse.tv/animation-composer)

Comment: Can you add some more detail to this? Maybe outline the steps needed to animate like the OP requested?